# Create a Hand In Items In SharePoint 2010

Tags: permissions, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I work for a school district and am implementing SharePoint 2010.  We are trying to determine how to create a hand in (students can drop files into but not view and staff members can view) document library or folder.

Has anyone tried doing something like this or is there a better way?

Thanks,

Comment: This is a good question - I am sure there are many people who need to accept files from anyone into a given folder, but don't want to give everyone access to that folder.

Answer (score 4):

Doc library settings:

1. Versioning settings - Require Content Approval = Yes
2. Who should see draft items... Select 'Only users who can approve (and the author)'
3. Default view - Created by = [Me]   if you are not anonymous access enabled.
4. Add staff members to the Approvers group

Everyone else (students) is in the Contributors group.
As an item is uploaded, by default it will be in Draft status. So, only Approvers and the Author can see it until Approved.

Answer (score 3):

You can consider using the **incoming e-mail** feature - you can configure a document library in a way that will allow students to 'upload' documents by e-mailing them to an appropriate address (e.g. *handin@your-school.edu*), even though they have no access to this library.

- [Plan incoming e-mail (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263260.aspx)
- [Configure incoming e-mail (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947.aspx)